# TableViewCell does not change Label colour

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am facing problem in UITableView. I want change the label color on some condition. But it does not change on first reload. But when I start scrolling the new reusable cell change the text color.

Here is my code

I tried `setNeedDesplay()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` but not working either.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! WalletHistoryCell

        let item = array[indexPath.row]


        let amountDouble = Float(item.amount ?? "0.0")
        cell.labelAmount.text = String.init(format: Constants.AMOUNT_PLACEHOLDER, amountDouble!)
        cell.labelDateTime.text = item.dateTime ?? ""
        if !(item.details?.isEmpty)!{
            cell.labelReason.text = String.init(format: Constants.REASON_PLACEHOLDER, item.details!)
        }

        if item.debit!{
            cell.labelName.text = item.toName ?? ""
            cell.labelTo.text = item.toNum ?? ""
            cell.labelAmount.textColor = UIColor.appDiscountColor
        }else{
            cell.labelName.text = item.fromName ?? ""
            cell.labelTo.text = item.phoneNumber ?? ""
            cell.labelAmount.textColor = UIColor.appHopOrbitColor
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Could you attach some picture and sample project.

Answer (score 0):

By default it must work correctly. I.e. the problem not in TableView or TableViewCell. The only reason I can suppose is that `tableView.reloadData()` calls earlier than `array` updates. You can recheck this by printing `item` in `cellForRowAt` method.